# AdditionalFieldsProvider does not save configuration

Tags: typo3, scheduler

My scheduler task gets an additional field. Selecting an option in this selectfield is working correct, the task is executed accordingly. But if I open the task to configure it, the original configuration is not shown, it shows always the first option in my select field.

This is my Class:

```
class AdditionalFieldProviderSocialHubImporter implements \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\AdditionalFieldProviderInterface {
/**
 * This method is used to define new fields for adding or editing a task
 * In this case, it adds an email field
 *
 * @param array $taskInfo Reference to the array containing the info used in the add/edit form
 * @param object $task When editing, reference to the current task object. Null when adding.
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController $parentObject Reference to the calling object (Scheduler's BE module)
 * @return array Array containing all the information pertaining to the additional fields
 */
public function getAdditionalFields(array &$taskInfo, $task, \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController $parentObject) {
    $additionalFields = array();
    if (empty($taskInfo['replaceVideoStreams']) || $taskInfo['replaceVideoStreams'] === 'false') {
        $taskInfo['replaceVideoStreams'] = 'false';
        $optionTrue = '';
        $optionFalse = 'selected';
    } else {
        $optionTrue = 'selected';
        $optionFalse = '';
    }
    // Write the code for the field
    $fieldID = 'task_replaceVideoStreams';

    $fieldCode = '<select name="tx_scheduler[replaceVideoStreams]" id="' . $fieldID . '">
      <option value="false" '.$optionFalse.'>false</option>
      <option value="true" '.$optionTrue.'>true</option>
    </select>';

    $additionalFields[$fieldID] = array(
        'code' => $fieldCode,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:exutectmaps/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_exutecmaps_domain_model_feeds.replaceVideoStreams',
        'cshKey' => '_MOD_system_txschedulerM1',
        'cshLabel' => $fieldID
    );
    return $additionalFields;
}
/**
 * This method checks any additional data that is relevant to the specific task
 * If the task class is not relevant, the method is expected to return TRUE
 *
 * @param array $submittedData Reference to the array containing the data submitted by the user
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController $parentObject Reference to the calling object (Scheduler's BE module)
 * @return boolean TRUE if validation was ok (or selected class is not relevant), FALSE otherwise
 */
public function validateAdditionalFields(array &$submittedData, \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController $parentObject) {
    return TRUE;
}
/**
 * This method is used to save any additional input into the current task object
 * if the task class matches
 *
 * @param array $submittedData Array containing the data submitted by the user
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask $task Reference to the current task object
 * @return void
 */
public function saveAdditionalFields(array $submittedData, \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask $task) {
    $task->replaceVideoStreams = $submittedData['replaceVideoStreams'];
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add something like the following to the beginning of your `getAdditionalFields()` method - `$taskInfo` just contains values submitted in the client, if adding or editing a task, these values have to be initialized first.

```
// assign default value
if (!isset($taskInfo['replaceVideoStreams'])) {
    $taskInfo['replaceVideoStreams'] = 'false';
    // assign value of task currently being edited
    if ($parentObject->CMD === 'edit') {
        $taskInfo['replaceVideoStreams'] = $task->replaceVideoStreams;
    }
}
```

The code of an [example in the TYPO3 core](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Example/SleepTaskAdditionalFieldProvider.php#L33) is similar to that and concerns the `add` command in addition.